# Using WebDriverWait to wait if value changes after some time

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriverwait

I'm using `WebDriverWait` to get the value of a `WebElement` after some time, but if it doesn't change, I don't want it to fail, just get the current value and keep going with the execution.

I'm running a process in a Web that has a "process completed" label that I use to check if it finished. On the same screen there is an "elapsed time" for the process that I need to read to report how much time it took to run the process.
The issue is that there is a backend process running even after the "process completed" label appeared, and the time gets updated. I can't know how much time this "backend update" will take, and I don't know if in happy runs it can appear before mentioned label, for the moment, from my tests it goes from 10 to 40 seconds (60 to be sure).

We have a `Waits` class for this kind of stuff, but we didn't have a method for this text change validation, so I came up with this:

```
private static WebDriverWait _customWait(int value) => new WebDriverWait(
    clock,
    Driver.Instance,
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value),
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Settings.Timeouts.SleepIntervalInMillis));

public static void WaitForTextElementToChange(Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> elementFinder, IWebDriver driver, int time)
{
    string oldValue = elementFinder.Invoke(driver).Read();
    _customWait(time).Until(drv =>
    {
        try
        {
            return !elementFinder.Invoke(driver).Read().Contains(oldValue);
        }
        catch (NotFoundException)
        {
            return true;
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

This works. And I remark it because I don't fully understand yet the syntax and logic behind that `Until` method, I know that it gives a `WebDriverTimeoutException` and I left it that way to be an additional method for the framework.

So, if the value changes it gets out and keeps running lovely, but in this particular case, if it doesn't change, I don't need it to throw that exception so I called it within a `try/catch`.

```
Waits.WaitForProcessToFinish(drv => processCompleteLabel); //<- context code
try
{ 
    //If value changes before 60 secs everything is fine
    Waits.WaitForTextElementToChange(drv => timeElement, someDriverObject, 60); 
    //60 is a hardcoded int value just for testing
}
catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
{ 
    //But if it doesn't change just do nothing 
}
string timeElapsed = timeElement.Read(); //<- context code
```

My question is, would it be ok to leave it that way?
What would you do instead?

Comment: StaleElement should be thrown if the element changes, so you could just check for that on the original element and confirm expected text after it's thrown.

Comment: I've been playing a little with the code and despite the fact that the element changes its value it doesn't throw that exception. Here's the html code, while looking at it in inspect mode the `div` and `Time Elapsed : ##:##` texts flash and the value gets updated. I guess normal behavior.

`<div class="time-elapsed-heading">Time Elapsed : 00:10</div>`

But I can't see where I should make a change to try your idea. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: not real sure, but element.getText() seems like it would throw stale element if the "time elapsed" text had been updated.   Try getting the element after the process complete label appears and then sleep for 60 secs.  Try getting the text from that same element and then see if an exception is thrown.  If so, it's been updated.  (obviously it's better to put in an assert on the server side... if label's updated while backend process still running, assert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I see in the source I don't think there is a way around this with how [Until](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/3f0dd430fd80d8b9b86a50e37ff61b917bda09a8/dotnet/src/webdriver/Support/DefaultWait%7BT%7D.cs#L142) works.

The Until method executes a method passed to it in a loop until either a bool or object is returned or the timeout occurs.

```
public virtual TResult Until<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> condition)
{
    if (condition == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("condition", "condition cannot be null");
    }

    var resultType = typeof(TResult);
    if ((resultType.IsValueType && resultType != typeof(bool)) || !typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom(resultType))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Can only wait on an object or boolean response, tried to use type: " + resultType.ToString(), "condition");
    }

    Exception lastException = null;
    var endTime = this.clock.LaterBy(this.timeout);
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = condition(this.input);
            if (resultType == typeof(bool))
            {
                var boolResult = result as bool?;
                if (boolResult.HasValue && boolResult.Value)
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (result != null)
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!this.IsIgnoredException(ex))
            {
                throw;
            }

            lastException = ex;
        }

        // Check the timeout after evaluating the function to ensure conditions
        // with a zero timeout can succeed.
        if (!this.clock.IsNowBefore(endTime))
        {
            string timeoutMessage = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Timed out after {0} seconds", this.timeout.TotalSeconds);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.message))
            {
                timeoutMessage += ": " + this.message;
            }

            this.ThrowTimeoutException(timeoutMessage, lastException);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(this.sleepInterval);
    }
}
```

What you're doing works, But I would suggest having your own timeout loop without using Wait.Until() since it's core function is to throw an exception if there is an issue.

Comment: So I assume by reading this that the answer is "don't do it and make your own custom method", sounds right to me but I was hoping to not have to do it honestly. Anyway, I'll have to play a little more with that `Until` then. Thanks!